# How can you programmatically control a Casio Exilim EX-F1 digital camera?

Tags: camera

I would like to be able to programmatically emulate a shutter button press on my Casio Exilim EX-F1 digital camera.

It comes with a USB tethered remote control that can emulate a shutter press, so I would think there is a way to emulate that from a PC.

I've looked and can't find any libraries or anything for controlling this camera.

Anybody have any ideas?  How about a way to "sniff" the USB being sent from the remote (I can't imagine that's easy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this question, Casio finally released an official way to do this with the free EX-F1 Controller software (with special firmware included):

http://support.casio.com/download.php?rgn=5&cid=001&pid=573

It has its limitations but it makes more possible for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok although it might be out-of-the-box thinking the easiest solution I can think of, without having the patent documentation + technical specs in-front of me (that is the normal route people use to do this sort of thing) you could always use Lego Mindstorm robotics.

**Edit:** Anyways besides the Lego, which would be my course of action, I mentioned, the hard-core way is to use the Spec sheets, you can normally get them off the website, but then your basically into driver programming. If you find that prospect attractive in anyway [this link](http://www.embedded.com/story/OEG20020321S0027) will give you some ideas for doing it on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that might be my best chance.  There are kits specially made for this type of thing (primarily for non-digital cameras) but they're too expensive for my playing around.  Might bust out the Lego brick this weekend.  Not giving up hope on a USB solution yet though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a non-official API to control the Casio EX-F1. It's a reverse enginyering free (as in freedom) product.

http://code.google.com/p/exf1ctrl/